# How do I hide my custom Unity panel indicators from another user account on the same machine?

Tags: unity, indicator, panel, multi-user

I created a second user account on my machine, making it a "standard" user account. When I log into that account, most of the panel indicators I've added in my own administrator user account show up here as well -- but not all of them (e.g., the cpufreq indicator shows up in both accounts, but the multiload indicator does not show up in the second account). I'd like to prevent everything but the default panel indicators from a fresh Ubuntu install showing up in the second user's panel.

Edit 1: this is all I see in /etc/skel ...

> $ ls -al /etc/skel
>      total 40
>      drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 25 12:07 .
>      drwxr-xr-x 160 root root 12288 Sep 25 21:44 ..
>      -rw-r--r--   1 root root   220 Apr  3 11:58 .bash_logout
>      -rw-r--r--   1 root root  3486 Apr  3 11:58 .bashrc
>      -rw-r--r--   1 root root  8445 Apr 16 14:09 examples.desktop
>      -rw-r--r--   1 root root   675 Apr  3 11:58 .profile

Comment: My interim hackish workaround was to log into the second account, then go to Startup Applications, and uncheck all of these indicators. But that's not ideal, since the user of the second account could just go revert what I did.